# Chrome/Safari image height issue on first time page load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, frontend

I am doing my first website and decided to use Bootstrap3. I've started to work over section with four 'feature' columns with one image per one of them. I am including link to my developer version of it:

http://tymekpudlik.github.io/kajtek/

**In Chrome/Safari there is a problem that four image-icons (section where is a brain image) have much bigger height that they should have when we launch the site for the first time.** When I open Chrome DevTools and click on css height property for image and enter one more time same, percentage value (90%), images are changing to correct size. Issue persists only for Chrome/Safari.

There is nothing special in css properties for image:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
}
```

I'll really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change stye of the parent element of that img (i.e div with class "feature text-center") as

`height:auto;` instead of `height:100%;`

This trick may help you..

Comment: Great! Thank you, I never thought it will so easy to resolve. It is working properly now. Thanks one more time!